# Equality operator in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to write a `mixin` in `Jade`. I would like to pass a parameter through mixin to build same type of block with different value at different states. In the mixin I want to write a conditional that checks if passed parameter is equal to some value. But unfortunately it is not working and I can't find proper documentation anywhere. My code section is following:

```
mixin test(id)
    if territoryList
        each val in territoryList
            - if (val.parentArea==id){
                button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block=val.name
            - }
```

And I am calling it like `test('1')`

What is the problem?

Comment: remove braces from your `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your `if` is supposed to be a javascript `if`.

Don't you want this ?

```
mixin test(id)
    if territoryList
        each val in territoryList
            if val.parentArea==id
                 button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block= val.name
```